# toDataUrl rasterizehtml.js not working

Tags: javascript, html, rasterize

I am using rasterizehtml.js plugin to render my html into canvas!
I got some issues but managed to fix all of them except the very important one.
I am getting problems with toDataUrl(); it shows that it is blocked. 
I googled a lot. There were some stuff concerning that but i found no solution to my question.

The error is this one: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=294129) and [Safari](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17352) both have issues reported for what you seem to be seeing. `<foreignObject>` elements in SVGs will taint the canvas for both browsers thus making `toDataUrl` fail. See [limitations listed here](https://github.com/cburgmer/rasterizeHTML.js/wiki/Browser-issues#webkit).

Firefox is working fine.